# How to attach click handler to content added later - J Query

Tags: jquery, dynamic

I have HTML that looks like.

```
<ul>
     <li>
        <a id="MP0003631" class="pheno" href="#">nervous system phenotype</a>
    </li>
<ul>
```

When clicked, the JQuery, looking like this:

```
$(".pheno").on("click", function(){
var id = $(this).attr("id");

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "treescript.php",
    data: { pheno: id}
    }).done(function( msg ) {
     $('#'+id).after("<br>"+msg+"");
     alert(id);
    });

});
```

Will create HTML that looks like:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <a id="MP0003631" class="pheno" href="#">nervous system phenotype</a>
   <ul>
       <li>
            <a id="MP0003632" class="pheno" href="#">abnormal nervous system morphology</a>
       </li>
        <li>
            <a id="MP0003633" class="pheno" href="#">abnormal nervous system physiology</a>
        </li>
   </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

The problem is, the content that is being created, does not get recognized by the JQuery.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) in delegated mode to attach to any element that is added at a later point in time that matches your selector.

```
$("#dataTable tbody").on("click", "tr", function(event){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

The above matches any `tr` that are added dynamically to `#dataTable tbody` (which must exist when the above code executes).

You can also use the form

```
$(document).on("click", "tr", function(event){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

to add the click handler to *any* `tr` that is added later anywhere in the document.

Comment: Thanks! I used the (document) one.  YAY :D